# Non-EU spouse of EU citizen travelling to Australia with the EU residence and travel document

Tags: visas, passports, australia

is it possible for the non-EU spouse  of the EU citizen to travel to Australia only with the EU residence permit card and a travel document (alien's passport) released by the host EU country, knowing that the Australian  authorities do not recognize the non-EU spouse's passport?

Comment: Are you concerned about entering Australia or about returning to the EU? What type of travel document is that, what's the citizenship of this person (if any) and which country issued the travel document?

Comment: I suspect that the answer is "no."  Have you asked at the Australian consulate, or consulted the Australian government's web site?  Here's the page for visitors to Australia: http://dfat.gov.au/travel/australian-visas/Pages/default.aspx

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what type of travel document you have and why you cannot use your passport?  At the moment nobody can give a definite answer without those and the info "Relaxed" has asked for.  Close voting as 'unclear'. Will retract when all the needed info is provided.

Comment: I edited it, I hope it's very clear now!

Answer (score 4):

You have a refugee travel document issued by Italy and wish to know if you can travel to Australia visa-free with this document.

Unfortunately, no, [you cannot use Australia's ETA programme with a refugee travel document](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/601-); only passports are allowed.

> To apply, you must hold a passport issued by one of the countries or regions listed below. If you hold a non-citizen passport or other travel document, such as a Certificate of Identity, you are not eligible to apply for an ETA.

However, you can still obtain a [regular visitor visa](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/600-) and can [apply online](https://online.immi.gov.au/elp/app?action=new&formId=VSS-AP-600) for it.